# Flutter: Only detect gestures within a image

Tags: flutter

I'm having some trouble with Gesture Detector. I have a set of images that I want to add a GestureDetector to. However, I only want the GestureDetector to be active within a border of the image. As seen in the images below. I have some images with random shapes that are transparent behind the images. I want to make a gesture detector that only detects the inside of these random shapes. The parts that are marked with green. I did this for the circle by taking the local.position of the taping and then checking if it was within a circle with x^2 + y^2 = ... However this can not be done with custom shapes. Could someone help me with an idea of how to solve this? If I just mark the image with a gesturedetector then is it also possible to tap on the transparent part of the image, which I dont want. Thanks

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lldIy.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not something, you will be able to do natively in Flutter. If you want to extract the exact region of interest, you will need to do image processing to find the right shape. Your best bet to do the image processing live is C/C++.
Dart has the ability to execute native C, take a look at this: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop

You should attempt to extract a polygon bounding box of the image areas and then use the polygon path values to draw a path using a [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html).

If you do not need to be exact, try to approximate the shape by a simple polygon path by hand. The user probably will not notice the difference.